# TensorFlow Federated Installation DOCKER

Tags: docker, dockerfile, tensorflow-federated

I'm currently working on setting up TensorFlow Federated using Docker. Here's the steps I followed:
Cloned the TensorFlow Federated repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/federated.git
cd federated
```

Since I couldn't find a Dockerfile in the cloned repository, I created one with the following content:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.10.9-slim

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy the local requirements file to the container
COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential

# Install TensorFlow Federated and any additional Python packages
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir tensorflow-federated \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the local code to the container
COPY . .

# Specify the default command to run when the container starts
CMD [ "python", "./your_script.py" ]
```

Built the Docker image:

```
docker build . --tag tensorflow_federated:latest
```

However, I'm encountering some issues during the build process. Specifically, I'm getting the following errors:

[docker build . --tag tensorflow_federated:latest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjRlG.png)

anybody knows what should i do?

Comment: It looks like you wrote the build command a second time instead of including the error message.  Can you [edit] the question to include the error instead (in plain text, not an image, not behind a link)?